# tapestry return zone and streamresponse

Tags: java, object, tapestry, zone

I need return the body of a zone and streamresponse.

I want to update a zone and returns a file.

The event in java will be like this:

```
Object[] onActionFromGenerar() throws InstanceNotFoundException{
        /**
         * Code
         * 
         */

        try(InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(cuaderno.getFichero())){
            return new Object[] {new AttachmentStreamResponse(input,"Transferencias"), tableZone.getBody()};
        }catch (IOException x){
            System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
            return new Object[] { Index.class } ;
        }
    }
```

but return a error.
Can only return tableZone.getBody();

How can I do?

Comment: what is that error? write question properly.

Answer (score 3):

You can't return both from a single action.

You'll need two actions.

1. First action returns the zone to update. It also uses `JavaScriptSupport.addScript(...)` to load the second action when the zone updates on the client (eg set `window.location.location.href`)
2. Second action returns the `StreamResponse`.

Comment: By the way, this is not a tapestry limitation, httpdoes not allow this.